# sed command gets me error Label too long: on solaris

Tags: sed, grep, solaris, xml

Given database name `oltt206` or `DB01` i wish to extract its respective `username`, `password` and `connection string` from the xml below:

```
wladmin@myremhost:/tmp$ cat /web/bea_apps/uat/Tomcat_Home_v9.0.56/TomcatNode01/conf/server.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8048" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!-- APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
          <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

    <Resource auth="Container"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        global="dsspeedCanweb"
        name="dsspeedCanweb"
        password="O9jYL3yhwMF_Ep8P"
        username="VEL_CAN_WEB_USER"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host36db06v.mybank.com:1521:DB01"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        initialSize="15" maxTotal="150" maxActive="100" maxWaitMillis="10000" minIdle="15"
        accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="90000"
        logAbandoned="true" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="7200"
        removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"
        jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer;SlowQueryReport(threshold=600000,logFailed=true)"
        testWhileIdle="true"
        validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
        validationInterval="30000"
        testOnBorrow="true" />

    <Resource auth="Container"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        global="canwebds"
        name="canwebds"
        password="bbgwfxt2Os_2024"
        username="CANADA_WEB_USER"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host36DB06V.mybank.com:1521/oltt206"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        initialSize="15" maxTotal="150" maxActive="100" maxWaitMillis="10000" minIdle="15"
        accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="90000"
        logAbandoned="true" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="7200"
        removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"
        jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer;SlowQueryReport(threshold=600000,logFailed=true)"
        testOnBorrow="true" />

</GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="12408" address="uswl1212mrshm01.host35as28v.mybank.com" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="12409" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
         SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
         library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the AprLifecycleListener.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
         the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->
    <!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
         This connector uses the APR/native implementation which always uses
         OpenSSL for TLS.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used. OpenSSL style
         configuration is used below.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                         certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                         certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="12404" address="uswl1212mrshm01.host35as28v.mybank.com" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="12409" requiredSecret="QmtmM3hWcEVzUW5VTDNLdQo=" />

    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="worker8">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
        Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className='org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve'
                showServerInfo='false' />

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

I tried the following command on solaris but it fails:

Error Output:

```
wladmin@remhost:$ sed -n '/<Resource/{:a; N; /DB01/!ba; s/.*password="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p}' /web/bea_apps/perf/Tomcat_Home_v9.0.56/TomcatNode01/conf/server.xml
Label too long: /<Resource/{:a; N; /DB01/!ba; s/.*password="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p}
```

Desired result:

```
        O9jYL3yhwMF_Ep8P
        VEL_CAN_WEB_USER
        host36db06v.mybank.com:1521:DB01
```

I would eventually take the solution to ansible.

Kindly assist.

Comment: Can you install xmlstarlet, xmllint? Do you have Perl installed?

Comment: GillesQuenot I do have `xmllint` on one of the host so i can try that solution. I m however, not the admin to be able to install anything on the target solaris host.

Comment: You didn't replied for Perl

Comment: @GillesQuénot sorry perl is not an option ... i prefer `sed` or `awk` as the work on most solaris and non solaris systems

Comment: sed and awk can't parse XML

Comment: It would be better to edit your XML file at bare minimum

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here the code for the password.

Adapt it to have the rest:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//Resource[@auth="Container" and contains(@url, ":DB01")]/@password)' file.xml
```

##### Output

```
O9jYL3yhwMF_Ep8P
```

The expression is [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath).

Comment: sorry the `xmllint` solution you shared does not take into consideration which database name is passed ... So i expect the password for `oltt206` or 'DB01` depending on whichever is provided as an input.

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: the solution you shared is not generic .... If the user provides Database name say `DB01` the solution command would get executed for any xml (not neccessarily this one) and the given DB may be `[1] or [2] or [3] or whatever` and i would not need all the passwords but just the password for that given database only.

Comment: Edited to pass the DBO1 parameter

Comment: @GillesQuénot Does `xmlint` allow us to parametrize the expression (as to not having to inject a shell variable into the expression if one wanted to make `DB01` a user-supplied value)?  Also, does `xmllint` not handle `ends-with()`?

Comment: AFAIK, using shell variable is mandatory. This is not `jq` ;) And `xmllint` use XPath1, so there's no `ends-with()` function. Can be done with convoluted one.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the subject, in your:

> ```
> /<Resource/{:a; N; /DB01/!ba; s/.*password="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p}
> ```

`sed` script,  with traditional `sed` implementations (the ones deriving from the original implementation in the 70s such as Solaris'), `:a; N; /DB01/!ba; s/.*password="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p}` is defining (attempting to define) a branching label called `a; N; /DB01/!ba; s/.*password="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p}`, that is `;` is not separating the `:` command from the `N` command, it is part of the label name. Same goes for the `b`, `t` commands.

It even used to be required by POSIX, and was only relaxed (on [my request](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=945)) in [the 2016 edition of the standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/sed.html).

So you can't have any other command on the same line after the `:`, `b`, `t` ones.

GNU `sed` doesn't allow `;` in label names, but still allows `;` in file names after `w`, `r`, `s///w` as still required by POSIX. For instance, `w file;d` writes to the file called `file;d`. So those (and `#` and `}`) cannot be followed by anything either.

Another thing not compliant/portable in your script is that you're not preceding `}` with `;` or a newline.

So you need:

```
sed -n '
  /<Resource/{
   :a; N; /DB01/!ba
   s/.*password="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p
  }'
```

Or if you need it on one line:

```
sed -n -e '/<Resource/{:a' -e 'N;/DB01/!ba' -e 's/.*password="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p;}'
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `xq` (part of [Andrey Kislyuk's `yq` distribution](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq); a set of parsers built on top of the `jq` JSON parser) and passing a string that will be used to match the correct URL from the relevant `Resource` section:

```bash
query_string=DB01

xq -r --arg query "$query_string" '
    .Server.GlobalNamingResources.Resource |
    map(select(."@auth" == "Container" and (."@url" // empty | endswith($query)))."@password")[]' file.xml
```

As you can see, the heart of this `jq` expression, where the relevant `Resource` entries are selected based on the `auth` and `url` attributes, reads similar to the solution from [Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/767934/116858).  The difference here is that the `jq` tool (which `xq` wraps) allows for creating internal string variables from user-provided data using `--arg`.  This means we can parametrize the command without injecting shell data into the expression.

I'm also opting for testing the URL using `endswith()`, so the user-supplied string will have to match at the *end* of the URL.

Running the above command would return the string `O9jYL3yhwMF_Ep8P`.

---

Using [Mike Farah's `yq` parser](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) to parse the XML, we can do something similar:

```bash
query=$query_string yq '
    .Server.GlobalNamingResources.Resource |
    map(select(."+@auth" == "Container" and ."+@url" == "*" + env(query))."+@password") | .[]' file.xml
```

The difference here is that we pass the user-supplied value to `yq` via the environment variable `query` and do a pattern match in the expression (which means that we hope that the given string is not a *pattern*).  Note too that Mike's `yq` uses a slightly different format of the XML attributes (with a `+` prefix).

Comment: OP had an issue, now he have 3 ^^  At least, OP have choice. Looks not natural to query XML with `jq`'s JSON syntax, but sometimes I use `xidel` to query `JSON` too :)